# Replace different rows of same data with different data

Tags: microsoft-excel

my title might be a little misleading, but I can explain further in here. Picture for reference:

[image: Sample Data]

According to the sample data given above, I want to ask is there any way to replace the "a" in column 2 with the data given in column 1, so that it will result in column 4?

Thank you in advance for the responses.

Comment: Can column 1 be anything of any length, not just sequential numbers or row numbers, or is it literally "1,2,3,4"? Is the "a" a placeholder for some uniform thing between the open parenthesis and the first comma, but not necessarily a single character, or is it literally "a"?

Comment: Like `SUBSTITUTE(B1,"a",A1)`?

Comment: @fixer1234 i figured it out, thank you!

Comment: @MátéJuhász i figured it out too, thank you!

Comment: Kudos for figuring it out.  Can you post an answer with your solution?  The purpose of questions on the site is to build a knowledge base of solutions for people to share.  If the question is unambiguous, people can share solutions even if you're already satisfied.  If it's ambiguous (like this one is), and you wish to just abandon it, it would be better to delete the question.  Thanks.